# Probability that three randomly selected balls are black given that at least one of them is black

Tags: probability

> A box contains $10$ balls, $6$ black and $4$ white. If $3$ balls are randomly selected with (without) replacement. Compute the probability that these $3$ balls are black given that at least one of these selected balls is black.

My try: Call $A_i$ the event: the ball selected in the $i$th trial is black. $i=1,2,3.$ So I think  we are looking for:
$$
P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3)
$$
which I am not capable of calculating at this moment.

My question is: is this thought correct? If yes how to calculate this probability. If not (or even if yes), is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, this is correct; use the conditional probability formula $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.$$

Comment: What do you mean by "... probability of these 3 balls are black ..."? This is not clear.

Comment: Note that at least one of the three balls is black if they are not all red.  Subtracting the probability that all the balls are red from $1$ makes it easier to calculate the denominator.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You edit may or may not be right. Also possible: "... probability that 2 of these 3 balls are black ..."

Answer (score 1):

Let X~number of black balls chosen.

We want to calculate $P(X=3|X \geq 1)$
$$P(X=3|X \geq 1)= \frac{P(X=3,X \geq 1)}{P(X\geq 1)} = \frac{P(X=3)}{P(X\geq 1)}=\frac{P(X=3)}{1 - P(X=0)}= \frac{\frac{6}{10}\frac{5}{9}\frac{4}{8} }{1-\frac{4}{10}\frac{3}{9}\frac{2}{8} }$$